# Why I can not found the specified thread in Asp.Net Framewok thread pool

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadpool

ALL

I was working on a little code which is for search a thread by thread id in the processes of computer.

All my code looks like below , Please help to review it.  :)

```
    using System.Diagnostics;

    public class NKDiagnostics
    {
        private Process[] m_arrSysProcesses;

        private void Init()
        {
            m_arrSysProcesses = Process.GetProcesses(".");
        }
        public static ProcessThread[] GetProcessThreads(int nProcID)
        {
            try
            {
                Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(nProcID);
                ProcessThread[] threads = new ProcessThread[proc.Threads.Count];
                proc.Threads.CopyTo(threads, 0);
                return threads;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

and In another class, I assign a thread to execute my function named `DoNothing`

```
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((t) => Utility.DoNothing((TimeSpan)t), 
TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

and the function `DoNothing` code is

```
public class Utility
    {
        public static void DoNothing(TimeSpan timeout, TextBox txtThreadId)
        {
            TimeoutHelper helper = new TimeoutHelper(timeout);
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000 * 5);
                if (helper.RemainingTime() <= TimeSpan.Zero)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("This thread's work is finished.");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {

                    if (Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread)
                    {
                        MessageBox.show( Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());
                    }

                }
            }
        }
}
```

My problem is the `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` shows 10, I searched it in all the process. But did't found it .

```
ProcessThread[] m_Threads = NKDiagnostics.GetProcessThreads(processId);
for (int i = 0; i < m_Threads.Length; i++)
            {

                if (m_Threads[i].Id.Equals(10))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Found it.");
                }
}
```

Am I missing something? why I can't find this thread ? please help me .thanks.

**Updated**

The original idea of mine to do some experiment with this code is trying to find a way to get the status of the managed thread. obviously in the way I posted here doesn't make it. so my question is how can I know the status of managed thread with specified thread id? thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Thread.ManagedThreadId` and `ProcessThread.Id` are not comparable. The first is assigned by the .NET runtime, while the second is the value of the native thread handle the OS assigns to each thread.

It is also [not possible to map one to the other](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74169f59.aspx):

> An operating-system ThreadId has no fixed relationship to a managed
>   thread, because an unmanaged host can control the relationship between
>   managed and unmanaged threads. Specifically, a sophisticated host can
>   use the Fiber API to schedule many managed threads against the same
>   operating system thread, or to move a managed thread among different
>   operating system threads.

Therefore your code cannot be made to work as is.

As an aside, there is a possible race condition here:

```
ProcessThread[] threads = new ProcessThread[proc.Threads.Count];
proc.Threads.CopyTo(threads, 0);
```

It is possible that `proc.Threads` is modified after the array has been initialized but before `CopyTo` executes. To avoid this race condition evaluate `proc.Threads` only once, for example:

```
var threads = proc.Threads.ToArray();
```

Comment: @Joe.wang: It is not possible to go from an (unmanaged) `ProcessThread` to a (managed) `Thread` or the reverse -- I thought that was clear.

Answer (score 3):

Process threads are *unmanaged* threads; a `Thread.CurrentThread` is a *managed* thread; while the two are related, it is not guaranteed there is a 1:1 mapping between the two, nor is it guaranteed that a managed thread stays associated with the same unmanaged thread.

I would suggest not looking at the `ManagedThreadId` if you are comparing to unmanaged threads.